# Specify type for @RequestBody when using an abstract class

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I have an endpoint that I have receiving an abstract class:

```
@RequestMapping(value = URL, method = RequestMethod.POST)
@ResponseBody
public ModelMap update(@RequestBody SomeAbstractClass form) {
      ...
}
```

When I post to it I get the error:

```
Could not read JSON: Can not construct instance of ..., 
problem: abstract types can only be instantiated with dditional type information
```

I understand why I'm getting this error, but I can't figure out where I would specify `the additional type information`.  Ideally I could specify the type of the concrete class through one of the annotations, but any solution would suffice at this point.

Comment: What kind of `HttpMessageConverter` converter are you using to convert the JSON you get from the client into a Java object?

Answer (score 2):

I believe you are uisng Jackson as JSON serailizer.

First of all make sure that you have

```
 <context:annotation-config/>
```

in your spring xml conf file.

I used to have the same issue De-serialization of Inherited classes I solved it by annotating it

```
@JsonDeserialize(as=Child.class)
public abstract class AbstractParent { ... }
```

Comment: Would it be possible to toggle that annotation using an application property?  For example `@JsonDeserialize(as=((useDog) ? Dog.class : Cat.class))`?